# How should I handle shared classes between the Game project and the Content Extension Library?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline

I've been using XNA for a while but recently I've needed to write a content extension library which I haven't done before. I need to import a *TextureAtlas* class from a file that is exported by a tool I wrote. The output of my editor is a serialized XML file that contains a list of all *StaticImages* and *Animations* in the *TextureAtlasFile* class that its serialized from. In my solution I have the *TextureAtlasContentLoader* project which holds all of the classes that I will need for the texture atlas both in game and for loading the actual content. The importer deserializes the xml back to a *TextureAtlasFile* and the processor converts it to a *TextureAtlas* to return after it is loaded.

The problem is that I have no idea how to share the classes between the content extension project and the game project that will be using the *TextureAtlas* class. I've tried referencing the content extension project in the game project and that works fine to get me pass compiling but it throws a *ContentLoadException* exception when I call

```
textures = Game1.content.Load<TextureAtlas>("MainMenu");
```

saying

> Error loading "MainMenu". Cannot find type Client.Render.TextureAtlas, 
>   TextureAtlasContentLoader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

The only other clue to whats wrong I have is a warning while compiling that says/

> Warning   2   The referenced assembly 
>   "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553, processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved 
>   because it has a dependency on "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently 
>   targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove 
>   references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your 
>   project.   Client

which leads me to believe I'm not supposed to reference it in the game project. So to summarize my question, how do I handle my *TextureAtlas* and *TextureHandle* class that both the content loader and the game project need without causing errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your shared type in another project (game library) that is referenced by your content pipeline extension project and by your game project.

You might like to create `TextureAtlasContent` and `TextureHandleContent` classes, and have your content pipeline use those, with your game using your `TextureAlias` and `TextureHandle` class (that way there's no need for an extra project). It's what's done often for classes that use the graphics device in some way (Texture2D and Texture2DContent for example).

---

Shawn Hargreves' blog has some excelent posts on the topic of the content pipeline (as well as many other things):

[Shawn Hargreaves Blog Index #Content Pipeline](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html#contentpipeline)

There are also many good posts on the App Hub forums, there's a dedicated section for the content pipeline:

[XNA Framework Content Pipeline - App Hub Forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/55.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, really helpful information and the blog post on content pipeline assemblies addressed my exact problem.